# Adding wsse:Security token with message signature

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsse

I am trying to send a request via web service (SoapHttpClientProtocol) method. Unfortunately for me, this request requires to have wsse:Security Token in soap header, with signature of request xml, and raw data of public key (as I understand).
Soap exammple how it should be:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
        soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
            EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
            wsu:Id="X509-D517D5F699516D846F15717371831011">
                MIIE_certificate_raw_data_==
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1">
                <wsu:Created>2021-03-15T09:39:43.086Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2021-03-15T09:44:43.086Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-3">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#TS-1">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse soap"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>Digest_Value</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-2">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>Digest_Value</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>Signature_Value</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-D517D5F699516">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-D517D5F6">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-D517D5F699516D846F" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2">
        <Tag1>
            <T>12345678</T>
            <B>2342</B>
            <C>3456345435</C>
        </Tag1>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What I have done:

1. Created class

   public class SecurityHeader : SoapHeader, IXmlSerializable
   {
   public XmlElement Xml { get; set; }

   ```
        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteRaw(Xml.InnerXml);
        }
   ```

   }
2. added class which adds SecurityHeader
   *SecurityHeaderExtension : SoapExtension*
3. into web.config:

   <system.web>








   </system.web>

And finally I am getting soap:Header <wsse_x003A_Security ...>  instead of soap:Header <wsse:Security  ...>

Can somebody give me a hand of help? I have read a lot links already, with no result at the moment...

UPD:
Partialy solved this issue by:

```
var requestContext = myWebService.RequestSoapContext;
var token = new Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityToken(certX);
requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
requestContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 5;

// Sign the message using the X509 certificate.
var messageSign = new Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.MessageSignature(token);
messageSign.SignatureOptions = Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.SignatureOptions.IncludeSoapBody | Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.SignatureOptions.IncludeTimestamp;
requestContext.Security.Elements.Add(messageSign);
var resp = myWebService.ExecuteCall(req);
```

Now I have problem with reading response, I am getting error: 'The signature or decryption was invalid'.
As I understand the problem is on my side, but not sure...